# springboot WireMock mock without parameters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit, wiremock

I have this mock that is working fine

```
stubFor(WireMock.get("/varela/offerszones?channel=123").willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .withBodyFile("zones_config.json")));
```

but I would like to know if it possible to mock it without parametes, because I've tried but it is not working

```
stubFor(WireMock.get("/varela/offerszones").willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .withBodyFile("zones_config.json")));
```

Comment: try and use WireMock.get("/varela/offerszones*") - where * will match anything after

Comment: I've tried but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL matching can be difficult to remember in WireMock. Check out the [Request Matching documentation](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) for more information.

You should be able to *equality* match on only the URL path by using `urlPathEqualTo` in Java (`"urlPath"` in JSON).

```
stubFor(WireMock.get(urlPathEqualTo("/varela/offerszones"))
    .willReturn(aResponse()
    .withStatus(200)
    .withHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    .withBodyFile("zones_config.json")));
```

The other options are: (listed as Java / JSON)

- `urlEqualTo` / `"url"`: equality matching on path and query
- `urlMatching` / `"urlPattern"`: regex matching on path and query
- `urlPathMatching` / `"urlPathPattern"`: regex matching on path only